# SplitIOPerSec Peformance counter always remain Zero

Tags: azure, performancecounter

I am working on application which fetch Performance counter from application hosted on azure portal and i got values of all counter except **SplitIOPerSec** , it shows me always **Zero**

What should be reason for that and what it indicates? , I have used following WMI query to fetch it

```
SELECT SplitIOPerSec FROM win32_perfformatteddata_perfdisk_physicaldisk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a valid query; perhaps the counter is genuinely always zero?

From the documentation here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776376(WS.10).aspx

> **SplitIOPerSec**: Shows the rate, in incidents per second, at which
>   input/output (I/O) requests to the disk were split into multiple
>   requests. A split I/O might result from requesting data in a size that
>   is too large to fit into a single I/O, or from a fragmented disk
>   subsystem.

The Azure infrastructure is intentionally opaque, but I would hazard a guess that in a shared infrastructure system like Azure disk writes will be highly optimized. Any fragmentation won't be visible to tenants like us!

Comment: so there is no meaning to fetch this counter as it always shows zero!

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother. If I reckoned I was having performance problems on a role, and it was disk bound, I'd just add another instance.